# Lifetime in rust and old iterator pattern

Tags: rust, lifetime

I've discovered Rust broke some old code and I was determined to fix it. Sadly, it appears that lifetime references have changed quite a bit and something weird is happening.
Field `Counter.data` is irrelevant, it's just used to show that there is some data I use and it's reference to generic stuff.

Here is the code:

```
struct Counter <'c, T: 'c> {
    val: u32,
    data: &'c T
}

struct CounterIterator<'c, T:'c> {
    iter: &'c mut Counter<'c, T>,
    num: u32
}

impl<'r, T> Iterator<u32> for CounterIterator<'r, T> {
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<u32> {
        if self.num  == 0 {
            None
        } else {
            self.num -= 1;
            self.iter.incr()
        }
    }
}

impl<'c, T> Counter <'c, T> {
    fn new(dataz: &'c T) -> Counter<'c, T> {
        Counter {
            val: 0u32,
            data: dataz
        }
    }

    fn incr(&mut self) -> Option<u32> {
        self.val += 1;
        println!("{}", self.val);
        Some(self.val)
    }

    fn iter(&'c mut self, num: u32) -> CounterIterator<'c, T> {
        CounterIterator {
            iter: self,
            num: num
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let val = 11u;
    let mut cnt = Counter::new(&val);
    for i in range(0,2u) {
        cnt.incr();
    }

    for i in cnt.iter(3) {

    }

    cnt.incr(); // <- commenting this out "fixes" the problem
    // Otherwise the error is 
    // note: previous borrow of `cnt` occurs here; the mutable borrow prevents 
    // subsequent moves, borrows, or modification of `cnt` until the borrow ends

}
```

What is the mistake here? 
How do I make this so 'Iterator' idiom ends borrow by the time it exits the loop, instead at the end of block its defined?
Also, what do explicit life times `T:'c` do?

For record I'm trying to achieve Iterator API similar to `str.chars()` in usage. If there is a saner way to do it, please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `fn iter`, the `&'c mut self` ties the mutable borrow of `self` to the lifetime `'c` of the `Counter`. By the time you call `cnt.incr()` you can't borrow cnt because.... cnt is still alive (so the `&'c mut self` is still borrowing it).

One possible way to make your code work is to move `data` in `Counter` instead of storing a borrowed reference to it, like this:

```
struct Counter <T> {
    val: u32,
    data: T
}
```

If you want to keep data as a reference, another alternative is introducing a second named lifetime to the `CounterIterator` struct, so that the mutable borrow to `Counter` can live shorter than `Counter` itself.

```
// we now have a shorter lifetime ('s) and a longer one ('l). This is 
// expressed to the compiler by the 'l: 's bound that says "'l lives 
// at least as long as 's"
struct CounterIterator<'s, 'l: 's, T: 'l> {
    iter: &'s mut Counter<'l, T>,
    num: u32
}

impl<'c,  T> Counter <'c, T> {
// ...
    // now the &mut self can live as long as CounterIterator, not necessarily as
    // long as Counter. This allows it to be released as soon as the iteration
    // is over and CounterIterator goes out of scope
    fn iter<'a>(&'a mut self, num: u32) -> CounterIterator<'a,'c, T> {
        CounterIterator {
            iter: self,
            num: num
        }
    }
}
```

For reference, since the language is still somewhat in flux:

```
$ rustc -v
rustc 0.12.0-pre-nightly (2e3858179 2014-09-03 00:51:00 +0000)
```

Comment: Just a slight comment. Even though I didn't use this solution, it's one of several correct ones. Other solutions include dropping mutability by using `Cell` or just waiting until borrow checker supports non-lexical scopes.

Comment: @DanielFath yes, there are other ways. There is also one where you define CounterIterator with two lifetimes (but it gets a bit complicated): http://is.gd/eMsLJd

Comment: Actually, that is the solution I was looking for. I just never managed to make the lifetimes work correctly. Could you add it so it doesn't get accidentally erased by the pastebin/playpen?